# IBM MQ throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException on SSL handshake

Tags: java, ssl, jms, ibm-mq

When calling:

```
MQQueueConnectionFactory cf ...
cf.createConnection();
```

The com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.handshakeCompleted method begins:

```
public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent event) {
 X509Certificate[] peerCertificateChain = event.getPeerCertificateChain();
 ...
```

getPeerCertificateChain in javax.net.ssl.SSLSession:

```
default X509Certificate[] getPeerCertificateChain() throws SSLPeerUnverifiedException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This method is deprecated and marked for removal. Use the getPeerCertificates() method instead.");
}
```

causing this exception:

```
Exception in thread "HandshakeCompletedNotify-Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This method is deprecated and marked for removal. Use the getPeerCertificates() method instead.
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLSession.getPeerCertificateChain(SSLSession.java:295)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.HandshakeCompletedEvent.getPeerCertificateChain(HandshakeCompletedEvent.java:173)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.handshakeCompleted(RemoteTCPConnection.java:2448)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext$NotifyHandshake$1.run(TransportContext.java:685)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext$NotifyHandshake$1.run(TransportContext.java:682)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext$NotifyHandshake.run(TransportContext.java:682)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

The project's only IBM MQ dependency is:

```
com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq.allclient:9.2.0.0
```

Why is javax.net.ssl.getPeerCertificateChain() calling that deprecated method?  It looks like the problem is in the HandshakeCompletedEvent class, not MQ.

Edit:  This issue started with Java 15.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Have you tried to turn on ssl debug? Do you have the correct certs in your trust store?

Comment: I thought I had been testing with different java versions but I wasn't because gradle was picking up multiple org.gradle.java.home settings.  I now see that this problem occurs starting in Java 15.  I can go back to 14 for now, but still... it's a problem

Comment: For what it's worth, it's not uncommon for libraries to need updates in order to run on later versions of Java. Does IBM advertise that `com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq.allclient:9.2.0.0` should work on Java 15?

Comment: Nope, I haven't seen any comments from IBM but I suspect an update will be coming eventually.

Comment: IBM system requirements show that 9.2 is only supported with Java 8 and 11.  Any other versions that may work would be used at your own risk as IBM would likely tell you to use a supported version if you have a issue.  I'll provide an answer with a link to the documentation.

Comment: This is the JIRA in case anybody is interested https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8241047

Comment: This bug has been fixed in com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq.allclient:9.2.4.0 from the continuous delivery release train and in com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq.allclient:9.3.0.0 from the LTS release train.

Answer (score 5):

In the latest release, they apparently provide JAVA 17 support.

Sources:

- https://www.ibm.com/common/ssi/ShowDoc.wss?docURL=/common/ssi/rep_ca/8/899/ENUSLP21-0278/index.html
- https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient/9.2.4.0/jar

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30399718)

Answer (score 2):

In your question you mention that this was failing with Java 15 and you posted a self answer to use Java 14 or earlier.

---

According to the "Supported Software" tab of the [IBM MQ 9.2 Detailed System Requirements](https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=0A8B49C00A0B11EABCF401BE73544226&osPlatforms=AIX%7CIBM%20i%7CLinux%7CWindows%7Cz/OS&duComponentIds=A004%7CC012&optionalCapIds=25) page IBM only supports MQ v9.2 on various versions of Java 8 and Java 11.

I am listing below the versions that show up on that page today (September 25 2020), but I would suggest always referring back to the IBM page above for current results:

- AdoptOpenJDK with OpenJ9 JVM: 11 and future fix packs
- Developer Kit for Java: V8R0 and future fix packs
- IBM Runtime Environment, Java Technology Edition: 8 and future fix packs
- IBM Runtime Environment, Java Technology Edition: 8.0.1 and future fix packs
- IBM Runtime Environment, Java Technology Edition: 8.0.4.1 and future fix packs
- IBM Runtime Environment, Java Technology Edition: 8.0.5.0 and future fix packs
- IBM Runtime Environment, Java Technology Edition: 8.0.6.0 and future fix packs
- Oracle Java SDK/JRE/JDK: 8.0 and future fix packs
- Oracle Java SDK/JRE/JDK: 11.0.1 and future fix packs

---

Using any version of Java not listed on IBM's official MQ v9.2 System Requirements page would be at your own risk.  If you were using Java 14 and had an issue that you needed to get support from IBM on, they would likely tell you that it is not supported at that version and to reproduce the problem at a supported version.

Answer (score 2):

I created a library that may work around the problem if you have programmatic access to the `MQConnectionFactory` . [legacy-compatibility-ssl-socket-factory](https://github.com/marschall/legacy-compatibility-ssl-socket-factory) gives you a `SSLSession` that implements `getPeerCertificateChain()` by delegating to `getPeerCertificates()` of a different `SSLSocketFactory` .

```
mqConnectionFactory.setSSLSocketFactory(new LegacyCompatibilitySSLSocketFactory());
```

Comment: This is a wonderful idea!

Answer (score 2):

IBM MQ client 9.2.4.0 supports Java 17

https://www.ibm.com/common/ssi/ShowDoc.wss?docURL=/common/ssi/rep_ca/8/899/ENUSLP21-0278/index.html

> **MQ 9.2.4**
>
> - Intelligent workload rebalancing with updates to uniform clusters
> - Security enhancements that build on the existing robust security mechanisms in MQ, designed to ensure that your mission-critical
>   business data is protected
> - MQ client support for new Java™ 11 runtimes
> - MQ client support for Java 17 runtimes

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=wnim9-whats-new-in-mq-924-multiplatforms-base-advanced-entitlement#mq924_new_multibaseadv__java17support

> **Java 17 support for IBM MQ Clients**
>
> - IBM MQ 9.2.4 adds Java 17 support for IBM MQ classes for Java and IBM MQ classes for JMS for Oracle and Oracle and Adoptium.

If using maven, you can likely fix via

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Use Java 14 or earlier.

Comment: IBM system requirements show that 9.2 is only supported with Java 8 and 11. Any other versions that may work would be used at your own risk as IBM would likely tell you to use a supported version if you have a issue.